# Unable to compile array.writeToFile in Swift; but in ObjC its okay

Tags: arrays, swift, persistence

I'm going over assorted Cocoa persistent-storage scenarios in Swift.

The **Objective-C** version compiles with out incident:

```
NSArray *ricArray = @[@"One",@"Two",@"Three"];
[ricArray writeToFile:@"path" atomically:true];
```

However, 
The **Swift** version doesn't work.  
The compiler doesn't believe the array has 'writeToFile'.

```
let docs = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory,.UserDomainMask,true) as Array
let pathToFile = docs[0].stringByAppendingString("/myFile.txt")

var shoppingList:[String] = ["Eggs", "Milk"]
shoppingList.writeToFile(pathToFile, atomically:true)
```

> ...swift:267:5: '[String]' does not have a member named 'writeToFile'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`[String]` is swift's native `Array` implementation, not an `NSArray`; swift's `Array` does not have a `writeToFile()` method. You can, however, easily cast between the two. This should work:

```
var shoppingList:[String] = ["Eggs", "Milk"]
(shoppingList as NSArray).writeToFile(pathToFile, atomically:true)
```